# JTree object casting

Tags: java

I have a number of objects (containing various unique strings + variables) that I wish to display using a JTree. So far I have written code which sets up the tree fine.

```
for(myClass Item : objectArray){
     ...
     DefaultMutableTreeNode newChild = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(Item);
     parentNode.add(newChild)
     ...
 }
```

I have then implemented the `toString()` method in `myClass` with an identifier of the object. So for example, my JTree looks like this:

```
    Root node
       + object1
       + object2
       + object3
```

Adding a listener, I want to be able to select the required object using the GUI, access it's method and display the object's member variables. However, I'm having trouble retrieving the object. In particular this line:

```
 myClass selectedObject = (myClass) jTree.getLastSelectedPathComponent()
```

which gives the following run time error:

```
   javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode cannot be cast to myClass
```

Is there not a way to undo the original cast? surely casting to a Jtree node just wraps the object up with extra methods and variables? I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want the getUserObject() from the DefaultMutableTreeNode. Then you can cast it to your class.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) 
                              jTree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();

if (node != null)
{
     myClass selectedObject  = (myClass) node.getUserObject();
}
```